# get free or used ram in android

Tags: android, memory

I want to get total and used/free ram, my code works fine on all android versions for getting total ram. But I want to get either free or used ram. How do I do that?? There are other questions like this but none of them works on all API levels. the documentation says memoryinfo class was added in API 16.

```
private String getTotalRAM() {
    RandomAccessFile reader = null;
    String load = null;
    long total = 0;
    try {
        reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
        load = reader.readLine().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
        ;
        total = Integer.parseInt(load) / 1024;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return total + " MB";
}
```

Comment: Which documentation are you checking? Here it says it has been there since API 1: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html

Comment: The property `totalMem` was added in API level 16, but `availMem` was there since API level 1. Maybe you could try that one?

Comment: and how about free mem?

Comment: Free means the same as available :) But this is a quite complex subject. I recommend reading this SO answer for better understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2299813/1395437

Comment: you are a life saver.

Comment: can you give me an example of saving current date and setting it in textview using sharedpreferences?

Comment: First try to do it yourself and if you are stuck then post a StackOverflow question with your code :)